# "Безопасность Windows" удаляет созданные мною проекты

Tags: python, windows, password, defender

Создал простенький учебный проект на Phython, частью функционала которого была работа с буфером обмена

При запуске в командной строке все срабатывает хорошо, но после того как я упаковал код в .exe-файл с помощью auto-py-to-exe, то при запуске получившегося приложения система безопасности Windows его тут же удаляла, отправляя в карантин

Я понимаю, что конкретно в моем случае все решается добавлением файла в список исключений, но мне интересно, есть ли программный способ как-то работать с буфером обмена не привлекая внимания защиты Windows

Вопрос интересен с точки зрения удобства "умозрительного" конечного пользователя приложения

```
import random
import time
import string
import colorama
from colorama import init, Back, Fore, Style
import pyperclip

def generate_password(length):
    elements = list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()<>')
    password = ''
    for i in range(length):
        password += random.choice(elements)
    return password

def check_password(password):
    strong = 0
    for i in password:
        if i.isdigit():
            strong += 1
        elif not i.isdigit() and not i.isalpha():
            strong += 1
    return strong

def print_in_time(text):
    for i in text:
        time.sleep(0.005)
        print('\033[0;32;40m' + i, end = '')

yelow_B = '\033[0;30;43m'
green_T = '\033[0;32;40m'
red_B = '\033[0;37;41m'
 
init(autoreset = True) #после выведения текста сбрасывает цветовые значения 

print(f'{yelow_B}Добро пожаловать в генератор паролей!! ~ \n')

while True:
    length = 0
    while length <= 6:
        try:     
            length = int(input(f'\nВведите число символов: '))
            if length <= 6:
                print_in_time(f'\nРекомендуем сделать пароль длиннее 6-ти символов \n')
        except:
            print_in_time(f'\nВводите только цифры \n')
    
    password = ''
    strong = 0
    while strong <= 4:
        password = generate_password(length)
        strong = check_password(password)
                       
    print_in_time(f'\nВаш пароль: ')
    print(f'{red_B}{password}')

    pyperclip.copy(password)
    pyperclip.paste()

    print(f'{yelow_B}Пароль уже сохранен в буфер ~')
```

Comment: Скорей всего проблема не в работе с буфером обмена. А в том, что exe не подписан валидным сертификатом. По умолчанию (скорей всего) установлено "не выполнять неподписанные приложения"

Comment: Может лучше проанализировать лог антивируса и выявить причину срабатывания? Либо путем исключения вызовов определенных функций найти ту часть кода, на которую реагирует антивирус?